# try to create if to stop get numbers higher then 20 javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

i tray to build function to show the high and lowest number but between 0 and 20

```
"use strict";
let scors = [50, 70, 60, 20, 15, 14, 12, 10, 9, 8, -5, 4, 16, 2, 17.5, 12.75];
function minMax(score) {
  let max = score[0];
  let min = score[0];

  for (let i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {
    if (score[i] < min && score[i] >= 0) {
      min = score[i];
    }
    //this part dose not work
    if (score[i] > max && score[i] <= 20) {
      max = score[i];
    }
  }
  console.log(max);
  console.log(min);
}

minMax(scors);
```

Comment: What do you expect the result to be, and what is the actual result you get?

Comment: i expect to get 20 as the highest but i get 50 the if section in the max part dos not work and its return 50 from let max = score[0];

Comment: Is your list guaranteed to always have at least one number between 0 and 20?

Comment: If you have that guarantee, then you can set your initial max to 0 and min to 20.  If not, then your code should address what happens when no qualifying score exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the conditions you applied, the **current score** must be greater than `max` and less than `20`.

```
if (score[i] > max && score[i] <= 20) {
      max = score[i];
}
```

This is an example of 4th first iteration.

- Iteration 1: `input: 50` > `max: 50`
- Iteration 2: `input: 70` > `max: 50`
- Iteration 3: `input: 60` > `max = 50`
- Iteration 4: `input: 20` > `max = 50`

> In the 4th iteration, the `max` is not assigned as `20` because it doesn't greater than the **current max** which is 50.

Here is the simple solution:

1. Add `score.sort();` for sorting the array before start looping.
2. Define the `min` with the last index of the array.

```
'use strict';

let scors = [50, 70, 60, 20, 15, 14, 12, 10, 9, 8, -5, 4, 16, 2, 17.5, 12.75];

function minMax(score) {
  score.sort();
  let max = score[0];
  let min = score[score.length - 1];

  for (let i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {
    if (score[i] < min && score[i] >= 0) {
      min = score[i];
    }
    // This part now works!
    if (score[i] > max && score[i] <= 20) {
      max = score[i];
    }
  }
  console.log(max);
  console.log(min);
}

minMax(scors);
```

Comment: This solution is a) unnecessary inefficient b) does mutate the input c) doesn't work on an empty array

Answer (score 1):

For the range of 0 - 20 you can bound the min and the max which would eliminate the need to sort the array.

Time complexity O(N).

```
'use strict';
    
    let scors = [50, 70, 60, 20, 15, 14, 12, 10, 9, 8, -5, 4, 16, 2, 17.5, 12.75];
    
    function minMax(score) {
      let max = -1;
      let min = 21;
    
      for (let i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {
        if (score[i] < min && score[i] >= 0) {
          min = score[i];
        }
        // This part now works!
        if (score[i] > max && score[i] <= 20) {
          max = score[i];
        }
      }
      console.log(max);
      console.log(min);
    }
    
    minMax(scors);
```